# font size in UITextView is little small

Tags: iphone, uifont

How can i make the font size of text in **UITextView** to max so that it is readable easily.

Currently i am using this one and i have tried all the **UIFonts** but all are unreadable.

```
self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-Bold" size:12];
```

Any ideas how to use the font size bigger without using **UIFonts**.

Have two UITextView and their sizes are

```
self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 283, 300, 55)]autorelease];


self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 339, 300, 80)]autorelease];
```

Text font size is smaller wants little bigger so that it is readable easily and fits in this UITextViews.

Comment: Why can't you just increase the `size` parameter to 14 or 16?

Comment: what do you mean by without using font, you don't want to define any font?

Answer (score 3):

You may use property of UILabel [adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) while setting up large font size.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:16];
```

Have you tried "System" I think that is what the default font is.

Comment: self.textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]; if you want system font